# How to dynamically define multiple polynomials inside a loop in Maxima

Tags: maxima, wxmaxima

So...I want to create five different polynomials inside a loop in order to make a Sturm sequence, but I don't seem to be able to dynamically name a set of polynomials with different names.

For example:

In the first iteration it would define p1(x):whatever

Then, in the second iteration it would define p2(x):whatever

Lastly, in the Nth iteration it would define pn(x):whatever

So far, I have managed to simply store them in a list and call them one by one by its position. But surely there is a more professional way to accomplish this?

Sorry for the non-technical language :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a subscripted variable is appropriate here. Something like:

```
for k:1 thru 5 do
    p[k] : make_my_polynomial(k);
```

Then `p[1]`, ..., `p[5]` are your polynomials.

When you assign to a subscripted variable e.g. something like `foo[bar]: baz`, where `foo` hasn't been defined as a list or array already, Maxima creates what it calls an "undeclared array", which is just a lookup table.

EDIT: You can refer to subscripted variables without assigning them any values. E.g. instead of `x^2 - 3*x + 1` you could write `u[i]^2 - 3*u[i] + 1` where `u[i]` is not yet assigned any value. Many (most?) functions treat subscripted variables the same as non-subscripted ones, e.g. `diff(..., u[i])` to differentiate w.r.t. `u[i]`.

Comment: Thank you, that worked like a charm :), we used the 1st option and also did a little trick: When operating with this undeclared array, we gave different values to the variables based on iterations. For example: (p[k]*p[k+1]),x:i ,  with i being the value of a previous iteration and x being the variable inside the polynomial.